# Output file size different from input file size in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I am reading a csv file of size 1073 MB. Without transforming, I simply write the file to my output directory. However, now the output file size is 802 MB. I don't understand why the file sizes differ.

```
schema = "order_id long,order_date date,cust_id long,order_status string"

orders_df = spark.read \
.format("csv") \
.schema(schema) \
.load("orders_more_than_1gb.csv")

orders_df.write.format("csv").saveAsTable("n89612.n89612_orders")

orders_df_out = spark.read \
.format("csv") \
.option("inferSchema",True) \
.load("/user/n89612/warehouse/n89612.db/n89612_orders/part*")
```

What would be the schema when the output is written into n89612.n89612_orders table? Would it be same as when we defined in our input schema?